# Sqlite with Flutter Desktop Windows?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, error-handling, flutter-windows

the app is work with android but not work with desktop

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation fou
nd for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite)

Comment: You will have to use https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi if you want to support windows. `sqflite` does only support Android, iOS and MacOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed in a comment `sqflite_common_ffi` allows using sqflite API on Desktop. It is not implemented as a flutter plugin as it also works in a regular dart VM.

You might read [this](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/using_ffi_instead_of_sqflite.md) to see how to use your existing sqflite code on desktop. But since it is always better to explain a little bit more than adding a link, here are the basic steps:

### Setup

First add the dependency:

```
dependencies:
  sqflite_common_ffi:
```

### Initialization

Then initialize ffi before running your app:

```dart
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

Future main() async {
  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
    // Initialize FFI
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    // Change the default factory
    databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I am not able to run `flutter build windows` generated exe, I don't know what's wrong but data is not work with sqflit ffi. But without release, usign `flutter run` it can work,

Comment: @NicholasJela you might be missing the sqlite3.dll. i added it manually to the release dir and it worked fine.

Comment: Need to add sqlite3.dll as specified in the docs: 
Should work as is in debug mode (sqlite3.dll is bundled). In release mode, add sqlite3.dll in same folder as your executable.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the `sqflite` only supports Android Ios and Mac.
Alternatively, you can either use Hive or sembast.

If you want to perform queries on the database I suggest you use sembast.

both the packages currently supports all the platform however if you are using sembast you have to include the package `sembast_web` for web support.

**Packages:**

`Hive`: https://pub.dev/packages/hive

`Sembast`: https://pub.dev/packages/sembast

`Sembast_web`: https://pub.dev/packages/sembast_web

Answer (score 0):

## SQFlite on Windows

```dart
flutter pub add sqflite_common_ffi
```

### Step - 1

Remember to Download Windows Binary
[Download SQLite DDL FIle](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)

### Path

Add the DLL File to this path
[image: sqlpath]

### Code

```dart
class SQFLite {
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }
    _database = await initWinDB();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> initWinDB() async {
    sqfliteFfiInit();
    final databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
    return await databaseFactory.openDatabase(
      inMemoryDatabasePath,
      options: OpenDatabaseOptions(
        onCreate: _onCreate,
        version: 1,
      ),
    );
  }

// based on what type of data you want to add your Table
  Future<void> _onCreate(Database database, int version) async {
    final db = database;
    await db.execute(""" CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
              id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
              name TEXT,
              email TEXT,
              password INTEGER,
              phoneNumber INTEGER
            )
  """);
  }
}
```

### Initialization

Either you can write this in the main function or if you  are working on separate file You can add it inside initState()

```dart
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    helper.initWinDB();
  }
```

#### [Github Code](https://gist.github.com/ayoubzulfiqar/ea0c22461075ce708a2abbca433a9744)

Answer (score -1):

As @alextk noted, you can use [sqflite_common_ffi](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi), to get the Windows support you desire.  Depending on your requirements, a pure Dart option may be a better alternative though.

If you just want to store key/value pairs, [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) is probably the way to go, but if you want to store objects, [ObjectBox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) is probably your best bet.

Here is a good article which contains a comparison of existing storage technologies for Flutter:

https://objectbox.io/flutter-databases-sqflite-hive-objectbox-and-moor/